# phpdocumentor2 Showing Source Code?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm having a hard time finding out a nice clean way to generate docs. PHPdoc still seems a little scattered.

In any case, I can't seem to get it to **generate source code with highlighting**, which I seem to have a compulsive need for - being a stack overflow user :D

Here's the command I'm running:

```
phpdoc project:run --directory /var/www/symbiostock/wp-content/themes/symbiostock/ --target /var/www/PhpDocumentor-output/ --template responsive  --sourcecode --force
```

Without the `--force` parameter, it tells me I have too many arguments. With it, it just rolls through everything without any apparent generating of highlighted source code.

**Is this template sensitive? Only some templates do source inclusion?**

I find documentation on phpdocumentor slightly deficient in a few areas (ironically) so I thought I might just post the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that 2.x has implemented the --sourcecode option yet.  It's available in 1.x, but 1.x does not handle new features added in PHP 5.3 and beyond.

Comment: @ashnazg is there any updates on this? As I am still facing this issue.

Comment: I have it working in v 2.9.0 with the 'clean' template, but for a change it can't be turned off. You can hide the source code by deleting the 'files' directory or at least the .php.txt files in it